# How to insert a node as parent of another node

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to add a node as parent of an existing node. Say, my html code is as follows

```
<p>My tag</p>
<img src='somesrc.png'/>
...
...
```

I want to add an anchor as parent to the `img` node resulting in following code

```
<p>My tag</p>
<a href='somelink'><img src='somesrc.png'/></a>
...
...
```

I haven't found anything in Domdocument which can add a node as parent of another node. There is `appendchild()` method for adding child, but there is nothing to add parent directly. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why the downvote? A comment would be nice.

Comment: I don't know why this has been down voted... I marked it as duplicate because it is really close from what you want.

Comment: It was probably downvoted because the OP did not show what they had tried - there was no code included and the OP asked a "best way" question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard indeed

Comment: @Brewal Thanks. It's close to what I want, but there was no way I would've found that.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have tried some variation with `appendChild` as I mentioned, but it's not worth mentioning here as it does not provide right solution in all cases. I meant the right way. I had searched a lot for a solution, but the search term is different in the duplicate answer. This one is more generic. So, I'm keeping this alive instead of deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If you're using jQuery you can use [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).</s>

If you want to use native Javascript then the best approach would to be to do it the other way around - create the anchor and then use appendChild to move the img element to it since appendChild will move the element when it is already in the DOM.

Oops, wrong API. Sorry. Answer is pretty much the same. Create the anchor, use replaceChild to put it where the img is and then move the img to the anchor.

Comment: Tags are `php` and `domdocument`

Comment: I need solution with domdocument. Not with jquery

Comment: Sorry, I obviously need more coffee. The API is very similar though.

Comment: @Simon Thanks. `replaceChild` is the correct method. I'm accepting this answer. But if you elaborate a little more, others might find this more helpful in future.